# accidentally deleted dhcpcd5 package

Tags: apt, software-installation, wifi, dhcpcd

I have deleted dhcpcd5 package with the  `sudo apt-get purge dhcpcd5` command and now my wireless interface isn’t recognized, so I can’t install it again. How can I access the internet again without this package?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using one of the normal routers, you can change your network interface configuration from DHCP to static.

there is a lot of ways for that, and they are different from distro to distro.
if you are using Gnome NetworkManager, you can simply go into the wireless configurations and change it from DHCP to Manual and then add static IP for your machine. Please be sure that you are using unique IP address that your router didn't assign it to another machine.

also, you can download the `dhcpcd` package by your mobile or other devices and install it manually on your machine.